# OSX indigo opencv linking problem (cv_bridge, image_view)

Tags: opencv, ros-indigo, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install indigo from source on a mac recently upgraded to yosemite (10.10).  I've had a few issued but managed to build everything up to cv_bridge.  cv_bridge has a linking error with opencv:

```
Linking CXX shared library /.../devel_isolated/cv_bridge/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv_bridge/boost/cv_bridge_boost.so
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::Exception::Exception(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
  NumpyAllocator::allocate(int, int const*, int, int*&, unsigned char*&, unsigned char*&, unsigned long*) in module_opencv2.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [/.../devel_isolated/cv_bridge/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv_bridge/boost/cv_bridge_boost.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/cv_bridge_boost.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Based on some older answers, it looked like this was a libc++ vs libstdc++ issue (http://answers.ros.org/question/95056/building-rosconsole-osx-109/), so after adding:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -stdlib=libstdc++")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}  -stdlib=libstdc++")
```

cv_bridge compiled fine, as did everything up to image_view.  image_view also had an opencv linking error:

```
Linking CXX executable /.../image_view/lib/image_view/disparity_view
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::imwrite(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > const&)", referenced from:
... many more opencv missing symbols ...
```

Making the same change to CMakeLists for image_view, however, causes linking error to ros core libraries:

```
Linking CXX executable /.../image_view/lib/image_view/disparity_view
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ros::init(int&, char**, std::string const&, unsigned int)", referenced from:
  _main in disparity_view.cpp.o
```

I must be missing something here as it seems other people are having success with indigo on OSX.  Also, just to be clear, I have opencv 2.4.5 from homebrew-science.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206013/osx-indigo-opencv-linking-problem-(cv_bridge,-image_view)/) by [Mike Shomin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1719/mike-shomin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2015-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I uninstalled opencv2 and used brew install opencv --devel to get opencv 3. It got rid of the errors for that library...I am having trouble with the stereo_image_proc library though.

---

Originally posted by [Mr. CEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/21719/mr.-ceo/) with karma: 143 on 2015-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Shomin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1719/mike-shomin/) on 2015-03-26**:
Thanks for the tip.  Trying opencv 3 now.  Seems to fix things, but also brings a new problem.  image_view now complains about a missing function:
/.../image_nodelet.cpp:145:35: error:
use of undeclared identifier 'cvGetWindowHandle'

**Comment by [Mr. CEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/21719/mr.-ceo/) on 2015-03-26**:
I fixed that...Let see what I did

**Comment by [Mr. CEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/21719/mr.-ceo/) on 2015-03-26**:
This is a copy of my file.
https://gist.github.com/automagically/c844457eeb739759fbca

**Comment by [Mike Shomin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1719/mike-shomin/) on 2015-03-26**:
Gotcha, looks like you just skipped that bit if opencv3.  After a little opencv 3 name change in rqt_image_view, I am now up to image_proc.  Did you happen to run into a missing need for libopencv_contrib.dylib?

**Comment by [Mr. CEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/21719/mr.-ceo/) on 2015-03-26**:
I dont think I did....

**Comment by [Mr. CEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/21719/mr.-ceo/) on 2015-03-26**:
I assume you are doing the full install

**Comment by [Mr. CEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/21719/mr.-ceo/) on 2015-03-26**:
I have decided to do the barebones and install the libraries I need. It is what I should of done in the first place. If you need help I will still attempt to help you.

**Comment by [Mike Shomin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1719/mike-shomin/) on 2015-03-26**:
I'm trying for full... but I'm having to skip some thing.  I really need rviz though.  Through hacking, I've gotten there.  Now I'm having OGRE linking problems.  Tried to install ogre 1.9 through brew, but having a problem.

**Comment by [Mr. CEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/21719/mr.-ceo/) on 2015-03-27**:
Paste the error, and I will try to help (I wont be able to answer for a couple of hours)